# Summernote in Opencart 2x

Tags: opencart2.x, summernote

I'm using summernote editor in opencart 2x, but how i can add HTML  tag in code section ? when i copy code, summernote deleting HTML tag.

P.S: Please provide solutions without change summernote to another editor.

Comment: Please mention which page you have an error. Try fresh OpenCart version and replace with your js/editor section.

Comment: I used in Catalog --> Information.

Comment: Are you know about summernote editor? Please check there is code view symbol on it. Maybe that's why you are not able to view HTML tag on it. Because Default Opencart 2.x catalog → Information editor is working fine. If you still not fixing the problem then update your editor with fresh.

Comment: I updated the summernote from 0.5 to 0.8 but the problem did not resolve (just continues

Comment: you can try this one free: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29817&filter_search=ckeditor&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=45